# FFI std::ptr::addr_of_mut! vs mem::MaybeUninit segfault

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault, ffi, unsafe

I'm quite new to Rust and stumble about a question while playing around with the FFI. When I use an FFI call using a regular stack-based variable with a struct type using `std::ptr::addr_of_mut`, I end up getting a segfault. In gdb it looks like the stack gets corrupted and the segfault occurrs on the next function return.

```
    let mut termios = Termios::default();
    unsafe {
        tcgetattr(stdin_fd, std::ptr::addr_of_mut!(termios));   
    }

    termios.c_lflag &= !ECHO;

    unsafe {
        tcsetattr(stdin_fd, 0, std::ptr::addr_of!(termios));
    }
```

The struct and function declarations look like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Default)]
struct Termios {
    c_iflag: tcflag_t,  // input modes
    c_oflag: tcflag_t,  // output modes
    c_cflag: tcflag_t,  // control modes
    c_lflag: tcflag_t,  // local modes
    c_cc: [cc_t; NCCS], // special characters
}

#[link(name = "c")]                                                                      
extern "C" {
    fn tcgetattr(fd: c_int, termios_p: *mut Termios) -> c_int;
    fn tcsetattr(fd: c_int, optional_actions: c_int, termios_p: *const Termios) -> c_int;
}
```

I don't see why there is a segfault happening. There is an initialized variable on the stack and I use a macro to get its pointer for the FFI call in an unsafe block. Is Rust making any assumptions that I'm violating in the unsafe block which I need to communicate to the compiler (something like the `assume_init` in the second version below)?

The second FFI call (`tcsetattr`) works fine with `std::ptr::addr_of`. Is the problem from the first call not happening because it's immutable in this case?

When I use `mem::MaybeUninit` in the first FFI call, it works as expected.

```
    let mut termios = unsafe {
        let mut termios = mem::MaybeUninit::<Termios>::uninit();
        tcgetattr(stdin_fd, termios.as_mut_ptr());
        termios.assume_init()
    };

    termios.c_lflag &= !ECHO;

    unsafe {
        tcsetattr(stdin_fd, 0, std::ptr::addr_of!(termios));
    }
```

So whats's wrong with the first version?

(I know there is a crate for termios calls but I'm in the learning process trying to do things myself.)

Comment: `std::ptr::addr_of_mut!(termios)` can be just `&mut termios` and ditto for `addr_of!()`.

Comment: Thanks! But shouln't it be `&mut termios as *mut _` (according to the documentation of `std::ptr::addr_of_mut!` then?

Comment: References coerce to pointers, so `&mut termios` also works.

Comment: So the macro is only really needed for cases where the pointer is not properly aligned or points to uninitialized data, right?

Comment: Yes. Creating a reference, even temporary, in such cases is UB, so the macro is required. But in all other cases creating a reference and coercing it is more comfortable and more idiomatic.